# Creating new users to SharePoint list

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2016

I am creating new users to my SharePoint site using rest API but the problem is SharePoint accepts UserId to create new user . unfortunately  I only have account name and first name ,last name . Is there any work around for this ? Please help if anyone knows how to do this

Thanks
Sunil

Comment: More information will be required before anybody can answer your question. For example, provide a link to the documentation for the API that you say you are using. People need to know its name.

Comment: $scope.UserData.User=$("#UserDetails").val()
                $scope.UserData.UserId="-1"
                here user is people picker field and value that i am passing to it is i:0#.w|globaltest\someuser but its not accepting the value and bad request error .Since I am creating new user I pass UserId as a negative value but that's also not working ..

Comment: Might be duplicate of [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/205793/save-to-a-people-or-group-column-using-sp-2013-rest-api-by-login-name-only-with)

Comment: It's is but don't have solution yet